# JS making auto scheduler for shiftwork : unexpected "undefined" object key

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have been googling on this for 5 days and couldn't have found one solution. (deff Im' screaming inside)

What I want to do is rearrange like under below.

```
days = [[
  {first : {A: "1", B: "2"}},
  {second : {A: "3", B: "4"}},
  {third : {A: "5", B: "6"}},
  {fourth : {A: "7", B: "8"}}
], [
  {first : {A: "9", B: "10"}},
  {second : {A: "11", B: "1"}},
  {third : {A: "2", B: "3"}},
  {fourth : {A: "4", B: "5"}}
], [
...
]]
```

But `days[d][timeNames[t][roleNames[r]]] = nameNames[a];` is not valid I guess.

How can I make it run-able?

+If map() or reduce() would help, please use.+

```js
var timeNames = ["first", "second", "third","fourth"];
var roleNames = ["A", "B"];
var nameNames = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9",  "10", "11"];

var days = [];
var times = [];
var roles = [];

var pickedDays = 10; 
var pickedTimes = 4;
var pickedRoles = 2;

for(var d= 0; d<pickedDays; d++){
  for(var t= 0; t<pickedTimes; t++){
    for(var r= 0; r<pickedRoles; r++){
      if((pickedTimes*r)*(d-1)+r >= nameNames.length){
        var a = ((pickedTimes*r)*(d-1)+r)%nameNames.length;
        days[d][timeNames[t][roleNames[r]]] = nameNames[a];
      } else {
        var a = (pickedTimes*r)*(d-1)+r;
        days[d][timeNames[t][roleNames[r]]] = nameNames[a];
      }
    }
  } 
}
console.log(days);
```

Comment: I would try reduce the code and question down to a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). `Input`, and an `Expected Output` can help considerably.

Comment: @DaneBrouwer I did. Would you mind to have a look?

Comment: Tried to provide an answer before your edit. Lol, it's completely different to what I expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Found a solution to the problem, more verbose method. However, I'll leave it here for comparison.

```js
var arT = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth"];
var arR = ["A", "B"];
var arN = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"];
const [arTLen, arRLen, arNLen] = [arT.length, arR.length, arN.length];
const loopCount = Math.ceil(arNLen/(arTLen*arRLen));
let arNIndex = 0;

const result = [];
for (let i = 0; i < loopCount; i++) {
  result.push([]);
  for (let arTIndex = 0; arTIndex < arTLen; arTIndex++) {
     result[result.length-1].push({ [arT[arTIndex]]: {} });
     for (let arRIndex = 0; arRIndex < arRLen; arRIndex++) {
         result[result.length-1][result[result.length-1].length-1][arT[arTIndex]][arR[arRIndex]] = arN[arNIndex];
         arNIndex = arNIndex+1 === arNLen ? 0 : arNIndex+1;
     }
  }
}
console.log(result);
```

This loops to make sure every `name` of `arN` is seen at least once.

Answer (score 1):

Create `next()` method to get the index for `nameNames`. Once you are crossing the array boundary just start from index 0.

Once you have this method, you can generate easily using multiple `map` calls and `Object.fromEntries`.

```js
var timeNames = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth"];
var roleNames = ["A", "B"];
var nameNames = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"];

let itr = -1;
const next = () => {
  itr = itr === nameNames.length - 1 ? 0 : itr + 1;
  return itr;
};

const getDays = num => {
  return new Array(num).fill(0).map(() =>
    timeNames.map(name => ({
      [name]: Object.fromEntries(roleNames.map(x => [x, nameNames[next()]]))
    }))
  );
};

console.log(getDays(2));
```

Comment: Got two questions. First, What is the different compared with your code and ''const next = () => {let itr = 0; itr = itr === nameNames.length ? 0 ; 0; return itr;};"?
Second, why I get the message when I run your code "Uncaught TypeError: Object.fromEntries is not a function"?

Comment: @JustDoo, For 1) if define `itr` inside the array function, then the scope of variable is within the block. I put `itr` as global variable, so that function will not overwrite it.  For 2) because the Javascript or Typescript version you are using does not have the latest version. You can use the some `polyfill` or  just use the following method instead `const objectFromEntries = (arr) => {
  const res = {};
  arr.forEach(([key, value]) => (res[key] = value));
  return res;
};`.